# How would you graph $E=mc^2$ on a graphing calculator?

Tags: graphing-functions

I want to graph $E=mc^2$ on a graphing calculator but I am unsure how to format the equation to work; it's been $15$ years since I messed with graphs.

Comment: Replace $m$ with $x$, $e$ with $y$. So graph $y = c^2 x$, which is a linear function in the variable $x$ (i.e., mass). (Remember: $c$ is constant.)

Comment: Actually, why would you *want* to graph that?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I was thinking the same thing. :)

Comment: Just for me :). I can't post an image of the graph I want it to look like I don't have enough rep :/

Comment: Just for your information, graphing $e=mc^2$ might sound cool but is pretty useless in practice

Comment: @MatthewLozoya If you can't post an image directly, then you could put one on imgur (for example) and give us the link. That might help explain what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this equation is just a straight line passing through the origin, since $c$ (the speed of light) is constant. It looks like this (where $y=E$ and $x=m$):

[image]